# introduce a new widget called Related Articles. It is an OOB feature that shows a ML-generated list of articles related to the one being viewed

Tags: servicenow

In servicenow While viewing a knowledge article from the Service Portal or Knowledge Portal, you can see a static list of "Most Viewed" and "Most Useful" articles on the right-hand side.
We would like to introduce a new widget called "Related Articles". It is an OOB feature that shows a ML-generated list of articles related to the one being viewed. This would be dynamically generated for each article viewed.

We would like to introduce a new widget called "Related Articles". It is an OOB feature that shows a ML-generated list of articles related to the one being viewed. This would be dynamically generated for each article viewed.